# How do I use scatter plot size to represent frequency of x,y values as percentage of the total count of each x value?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm attempting to use a scatter plot to represent the popularity of certain streaming services based on gender. So far I've found solutions showing how to create a scatter plot where the size of the plot mark represents the frequency of each selection. However our survey yielded many more female responses than male responses, and I'd like the size of the plot mark to represent the frequency of each selection as a percentage of total selections by that gender. For example, say we have 60 male responses and 120 female responses, and 30 males and 60 females selected "Netflix" as their favorite service. Even though 50% of each gender chose "Netflix as their favorite, the plot mark for female choices is going to be much bigger. I'd like the size of the plot mark to represent the number of males(30) or females(60) who selected "Netflix" as a percentage of total males(60) or females(120).

I've tried manipulating the expression used in the plot.scatter() function in several ways but I can't quite seem to get it to work the way I want to. I've included my code below. I can provide the .csv file if it's required. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from collections import Counter

pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None)
surveyData = pd.read_csv('Survey.csv')



# Rename columns and remove Timestamp column
surveyData.rename(columns={ 'How old are you?' : 'AGE',
                            'What is your gender?(Optional)' : 'GEN',
                            'Which devices do you use for streaming video? (Select all that apply)' : 'VD',
                            'Which video streaming services do you use? (Select all that apply)' : 'VS',
                            'If you chose more than one video streaming service, please select the one that is your favorite. (choose only one)' : 'FVS',
                            'On average, how many hours a day do you stream video? (Enter whole number)' : 'VH',
                            'Which do you prefer - Video Streaming Services or Cable Providers?' : 'VP',
                            'What would be the main reason for this? (optional)' : 'VR',
                            'Which devices do you use for streaming music? (Select all that apply)' : 'MD',
                            'Which music streaming services do you use? (Select all that apply)' : 'MS',
                            'If you chose more than one music streaming service, please select the one that is your favorite. (choose only one)' : 'MF',
                            'On average, how many hours a day do you stream music? (Enter whole number)' : 'MH',
                            'Which format do you prefer - streaming music, radio, or physical copies?           ' : 'MP',
                            'What would be the main reason for this? (optional).1' : 'MR'
                            },inplace=True)
surveyData.drop(['Timestamp'], axis=1, inplace=True)

#convert stings within each column to numerical values for plotting
surveyData = surveyData.fillna('None')
gender = {'Female': 0, 'Male': 1, "None": 2}
svcs = {    'Netflix': 1, 'DirecTV Now': 2, 'Amazon Prime Video': 3, 'Sling TV': 4,
            'YouTube': 5, 'fuboTV': 6, 'PlayStation Vue': 7, 'Hulu': 8, 'YouTube TV': 9,
            'Twitch': 10, 'None': 13, 'Google Play Movies & TV': 11, 'HBO': 12}

surveyData["GEN"] = [gender[item] for item in surveyData["GEN"]]
surveyData["FVS"] = [svcs[item] for item in surveyData["FVS"]] 


#PLOT DATA
#Use Counter to set transformation of plot size relative to frequency of choice
x = surveyData['GEN']
y = surveyData['FVS']
c = Counter(zip(x, y))
s = [20*c[(xx,yy)] for xx,yy in zip(x,y)]

#plot with formatting
xticks = ['', 'Netflix', 'DirecTV Now', 'Amazon Prime Video', 'Sling TV', 'YouTube', 'fuboTV', 'PlayStation Vue',
            'Hulu', 'YouTube TV', 'Twitch', 'GooglePlay Movies & TV', 'HBO', 'None']

surveyData.plot.scatter('FVS', 'GEN', s=s, c='blue')
yticks = ['Female', 'Male', 'Prefer Not To Say']
plot.xticks(np.arange(14), xticks, rotation=-90)
plot.yticks(np.arange(3), yticks)
plot.xlabel('Favorite Streaming Services')
plot.ylabel('Gender')
plot.show()
```

Comment: Calculate the percentage first. This will be a number between 0 and 1. Then multiply by a number like e.g. 400 to convert to points and add some small number to have even 0 become visible.

Comment: I figured, where should I put this value though?

Comment: `s= your list of those values` inside `scatter`.